# Datatables ColVis plugin - hidden columns and column merge

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with 9 columns, columns [0] and [8] are hidden. Then columns [7] and [8] are merged together into one column (see code below).

The bit i am struggling with is using the ColVis plugin when i hide a column, the merging of columns [7] and [8] gets screwed up.

Hope that made sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var $buTable= $("#business_table").dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter:"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/business_serverside.php",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,       
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
        "sDom": '<"clear"><"top"CTilr<"clear">pt>',
        "aoColumns": [ 
            {"bVisible":false},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":true},
            {"bVisible":false}
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        $('td:eq(6)', nRow).html(''+ aData[7] +'&nbsp;'+ aData[8] +'');        
        },
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "oColVis": {
            "activate": "mouseover",    
            "aiExclude": [0,8]
        }
    }).columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ 
                    { type: "select"},
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "select" },
                    { type: "select"},
                    { type: "text"},
                    { type: "text"},
                    { type: "select"},
                    { type: "text"}
                ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are excluding column from allowing to be hid:

```
"oColVis": {
    "activate": "mouseover",    
    "aiExclude": [0,8]
}
```

But what I think you need to do is either a) exclude them both from being hidden so they never get tampered with, or b) write a callback method that chains their visibility states so if one gets hidden the other gets hidden automatically and like wise for their becoming visible.

Something like adding an fnDrawCallback in your datatable init:

```
// method gets called each table draw / re-draw
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    // column buttons get ids based on their column title 
    // so let's assume your columns are titled 'column7' and 'column8'
    $('#column7').change( function() {
        $('#column8').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#column8').change( function() {
        $('#column7').trigger('click');
    });
},
```

Code is untested but if you find you can't call events change events on $('#column8) and $('#column7') then you'll have to manually check column 7 for visibility. A random guess at how to do it would be something like:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
    if( fnSetColumnVis( 7, false ) ) {
        fnSetColumnVis( 8, false );
    }
    else {
        fnSetColumnVis( 8, true );
    }
},
```

Hope that helps!